# AsyncStorage Invariant Violation error when I try to import firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, asyncstorage

Whenever I try to import Firebase in my React Native app, it results in an AsyncStorage invariant error. I followed the documentation to install AsyncStorage, but the error remains. If I comment out the import statement, the error disappears. How can I resolve this issue and successfully import Firebase into my app?

Error message:

> ERROR  Invariant Violation: AsyncStorage has been removed from react-native core. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage, js engine: hermes

Line of code causing the error:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```